# Where can we read the TUGboat, the journal of the TeX Users Group?

Tags: tugboat, tug

The journal called *TUGboat* is the principal publication of the TeX Users Group (TUG). It exists since 1980 and is currently published three times a year. It contains technical articles as well as meeting reports and TeX community information.

How can we read it? Can we download it, and is the access restricted?

Answer (score 25):

**Great news:** all issues prior to the current one are now publicly available for download as PDF. That's a treasure of now 39 years of TeX articles.

Only the access to the current issue is restricted and is for TUG members only. Until earlier this year, issues became publicly available one year after publication. That was relaxed after a successful [open access survey](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/survey.html).

Here you can get access and further information:

- [TUGboat homepage](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/)
- [List of all issues](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/contents.html) with links
- [Category/Keyword List](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/listkeyword.html) with links to articles

The TUGboat is available in print too. The printed issues are mailed to regular TUG members.

The TUGboat as well as all TUG activities are for the benefit of the entire TeX community. The TUGboat is funded by member support. So please consider [joining TUG](https://www.tug.org/join.html). That way you can support TeX, and you get some [benefits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217685/) as well.

Comment: @thanks_in_advance Sure, I activated your account. See you there.